# ORACLE SSRS - Check if string is between range (or series) of strings

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have a where clause for a query made in Oracle like this:

```
WHERE ColX >= lowerLimit AND 
      ColX <= upperLimit
```

The thing is: ColX is type nvarchar and so are both limits (which are parameters asked to the user).

I am running the query with on Query Reporter and my results are fine. When I try this query on SSRS it fails, for some reason the

```
ColX <= upperLimits
```

starts acting like

```
ColX < upperLimits
```

ColX has data like: '000012345', '012345690', '000000012, '123456789'

Which are actually numbers, my work around was to convert them into Long data type in SSRS, but I was told I couldn't always do that because ColX might actually have letters.

So I was wondering how to do this comparison work with strings o something equivalent.